# How to find a specific word in the text and multiply the number of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code and I would like to modify it so the output will find only the myName and multiply the number of arrays so it'll still be "12"

```js
        text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Tk\
blah blah blah Tom blah blah Tom blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah T";
var myName = "Tom";
var hits = [];
// Look for "T" in the text
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
if (text[i] === "T") {
// If we find it, add characters up to
// the length of my name to the array
for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
hits.push(text[j]);
}
}
}
if (hits.length === 0) {
console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: I don't get it what you're trying to do here.

Comment: What do you mean with: *and multiply the number of arrays so it'll still be "12"*

Comment: I have modified the code a little so now when I execute I'd get array (12) :
T
k
 
T
o
m
T
o
m
T
undefined
undefined
]

I'd like the output would 4 times "TOM" :

12 (array) :

Comment: I think it's best if you just tell us what you want to achieve, on high level.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Try Google Translator, please.

Comment: Why 4 times Tom ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    const text = `Blah blah blah blah blah blah Bk
        blah blah blah Ben blah blah Ben blah blah 
        blah blah blah blah blah B`;
    var myName = "Ben";
    var hits = [];
    var start = text.indexOf(myName);
    while (start != -1) {
        hits.push(text.substring(start, start + myName.length));
        start = text.indexOf(myName, start+1);
    }
    console.log(hits.length);
```

Comment: every time u find "T" in text, your code add to hits 3 letters even if u find last letter in text. That`s why u have hits[10] = 'undefined' and hits[11] = 'undefined';

Comment: U must search full string 'myName' in 'text' so better to use 'indexOf' function or 'match'